# OpenSSH scp restrictions a-la gitolite

Tags: ssh, scp, authorization

Does anyone know of some software that would allow to restrict/tune the scp experience on a single unix user, based on SSH keys?

Similar to what gitolite does, or more flexible what rssh can do, but without chroot level tricks, so that any restrictions/limitations would be implemented solely by the alternative SCP subsystem implementation?

Answer (score 0):

meaning you only want the user with a certain pubkey to only be able to perform certain commands or only SCP?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402615/how-to-restrict-ssh-users-to-a-predefined-set-of-commands-after-login

there is, if i recall, a command string for remote scp calls. this can also be done via rsync.

but regardless, you can specify only certain commands for certain pubkey pairs via the link above.